# Google Datastore - Ensure only one entity is created for an entity with a specific ancestor key

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I want to ensure that only one entity is created for an entity with a specific ancestor Key. My solution is to put the ancestor query inside a transaction, check if the entity exists, and if not, create it.

Will this ensure only one entity exists with a specific ancestor key?

```
ofy().transact(new VoidWork() {
    public void vrun() {

            Entity entity = ofy().load().type(Entity.class)
                    .ancestor(ancestorKey)
                    .first()
                    .now();

            if (entity == null) {
                // Entity does not exist. Create it.
                final Entity newEntity = new Entity(ancestorKey);

                ofy().save().entity(newEntity).now();
            } else {
                // Entity already exists.
            }

        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SO doesn't like one-word answers so I can't just say "Yes".

If you're just trying to ensure that one and only one thing exists, you don't need the ancestor query - just do a get-by-key on a known id.

And since Java7 is gone, no reason not to put this in a lambda.

Comment: I need the ancestor there for other queries. Is this how a get-by-key with an ancestor would look like for one entity (assuming I know the parent entity id): `Entity entity = ofy().load().type(Entity.class).parent(ParentEntity.class).id(parentEntityId).now();`?

Comment: No, with `parent()` you pass in the entity object or a key object (see `Key.create()`). And the `id()` you pass in is for the child.

Comment: I see, so like this? `Entity entity = ofy().load().type(Entity.class).parent(parentEntity).id(entityId).now();` as well as `Entity entity = ofy().load().type(Entity.class).parent(Key.create(ParentEntity.class, parentEntityId)).id(entityId).now();`

Comment: Also, is it safe to use the parent entity Id as the child entity Id too? That would make it easy to see if a child exists for a certain parent when doing a get-by-key.

Comment: The code you quoted looks ok. Your second question confuses me. Keep in mind that the unique identifier for an entity is {parent, id}. Specific ids are only unique for a given parent (which may possibly be null).